# Combinations, when placing n objects into k boxes, each box has its own size and the order in them doesn't matter?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins, multinomial-coefficients

I have n objects and k boxes, each box has its own size. 
The arrangement of objects in a box doesn't matter.
How many combinations are there, respectively the formula?

Say we have 7 objects and 3 boxes with sizes of 2, 3 and 4. The solution is 6, the same result appears (it has to appear) when we place the gaps [(2+3+4)-7=2]

The multinomial coefficient only considers (I think so) the case when a box has to contain a specific number of objects, so the result is wrong: 
$$
\frac{7!}{2!\cdot 3!\cdot 4!} = 17.5 \not= \frac{2!}{2!\cdot 3!\cdot 4!} = \frac{1}{144}
$$
But what's the correct formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This count can be obtained using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as

$$
\sum_{S\subseteq B}(-1)^{|S|}\binom{n+k-1-\sum_{b\in S}(c_b+1)}{k-1}\;,
$$

where $B$ is the set of boxes and $c_b$ is the capacity of box $b$: If the restriction is violated for the boxes in $S$, we can put $c_b+1$ objects in each box $b\in S$ and then count the number of ways of distributing the remaining objects. Here, contrary to convention, the binomial coefficient is taken to be zero if the upper index is negative. See also [Balls In Bins With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm).

In your example, this is

$$
\binom92-\binom62-\binom52-\binom42+\binom22=6\;.
$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! But how do you got onto this, respectively deduced this with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: @RolWeb: You have $k$ restrictions; you can count the number of arrangements that violate any particular restrictions, and you want to use this to count the number of arrangements that satisfy all $k$ restrictions. This is a typical example of an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle. If you're used to thinking of the principle in terms of sets rather than restrictions, replace "arrangements that violate particular restrictions" by "arrangements that belong to particular sets" and "arrangements that satisfy all restrictions" by "arrangements that don't belong to any of the sets".